# My school said they can track what websites we visit and games we play via online learning. is this true or just a way to scare us?

Tags: privacy, websites, user-tracking

So my teacher caught someone playing a game in my online class and warned us that they have installed a new program so they can track "everything we do using our ip address" now im quite techy so im sure this is bs but i want to make sure, im on my home computer using my home internet and using google meets, there are some websites like exam websites that track how many times you leave the page but is it possible to know **everything**? Im pretty sure its validating my privacy but im not sure, thanks in advance.

Comment: No its a different situation.

Comment: How exactly is this situation different? I see in both questions the main point of using the own computer and the own internet.

Comment: Because in the other question there asking about how the school can track their account, my school says they have installed a program that can track everything no matter what because they have out IP adress.

Comment: The accepted answer is the same answer that applies here. If they have something installed they can track. If you question is about how they installed something in the first place, then that's not what you asked.

Comment: @Mark: To cite from the other post: *"But __software cannot be installed without you knowledge or consent__ (again... more sophisticated attacks exist, but are certainly not used to spy on school kids). However, __whether you gave consent and installed something or let your laptop be handled by school personal unsupervised so you aren't sure that nothing was installed locally, only you can know__."*